# Searching google drive from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

For my first google chrome extension I am trying to do the following:

- Whenever the user performs a google search:

  - Perform the same search on google drive
  - Display top X search results from GDrive next to normal search results

This is inspired by what the Evernote plugin for chrome does, displaying evernote "notes" matching the query in a box next to the normal results.

So far I have code that obtains the search string, and I can content into the correct place in the search result page. My concern is with google drive, I haven't found any **clear instructions on how to connect with the Drive API from javascript / a chrome extension** (if this is even possible?).

---

Bonus question: Originally I wanted to do the search in gmail instead of drive, but it appears there is no API for this? Would it be possible without an API?